# How to create a Map in a loop?

Tags: dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

i try to build a map to add it into firestore.

Produkt Class:

```
class Produkt{
  String name;
  int anzahl;

  Produkt({
    this.name,
    this.anzahl,
  });

  factory Produkt.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson){
    return Produkt(
        name:parsedJson['Name'],
        anzahl:parsedJson['Anzahl']
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toProduktJson() =>
  {
    "Name" : name,
    "Anzahl" : anzahl
  };
}
```

ProduktList Class:

```
  class ProduktList{
  final List<Produkt> produkte;

  ProduktList({
    this.produkte,
  });

  factory ProduktList.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson){
    var list = parsedJson["Produkte"] as List;
    List<Produkt> produkte = list.map((i) => Produkt.fromJson(i.cast<String, dynamic>())).toList();

    return ProduktList(
        produkte: produkte,
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toProdukteJson() =>
  {
    "Produkte" : [
      produkte[0].toProduktJson(),
      produkte[1].toProduktJson(),
      produkte[2].toProduktJson(),
    ]
  };
}
```

I wanted that the Map looks like:

```
{
    "Produkte" : [
      produkte[0].toProduktJson(),
      produkte[1].toProduktJson(),
      produkte[2].toProduktJson(),
    ]
  };
```

But if the List produkte has a length of 2, the Map should have 2 and it the List have a length of 10, the Map should have 10 entries.

How can i do this? 
Pls help me. 
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be the following:

```
  Map<String, dynamic> toProdukteJson() {
    Map map = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (produkte != null) {
      map["produkte"] = produkte.map((produkt) => produkt.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return map;
  }


class Produkt {
  final String id;
  ...

  Produkt(this.id, ...);

  Map toJson() => {'id' : id, ...};
}
```

Comment: This didnt work, because produkte is a list of Produkt

Comment: Well that assumes that you have a `Map toJson() => ....` method in your Podukt class.

Comment: I have changed the answer to take into account the `toJson()` method.